# best Social Network for Moodle integration?

Tags: moodle, elgg, socialengine, mahara

I´m going to set-up an adapted social network for my company and I need to be logged through moodle so I´m looking for the best option... any suggestion?

i´m gattering information about elgg, mahara, socialengine, Buddypress ... the most important is that we need users to be logged only one time

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by de way, the best opcion for me was Joomla + JomSocial(plugin) + Joomdle (plugin) despite Elgg is the best Social Network creator system, it hasen´t good connection with Moodle

Answer (score 1):

moodle social networking integration best option is joomdle (joomsocial extension).